# java.io.FileNotFoundException: fileprovider

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fileprovider

I realize there have been a lot of posts with the fileProvider but I can't seem to find an answer to my problem in there.

I take images, using the following intent:

```
private fun openCamera() {
    currentFocus?.clearFocus()
    val intent = Intent(MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA)
    if (intent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

To make this work, I also have an Observer:

```
 fun observe(): Flowable<Picture> =
        pictureSubject.onBackpressureLatest()
                .map { uri ->
                    appContext.get()?.let {
                        val cursor = it.contentResolver.query(uri, null, null, null, "date_added DESC, _id DESC")
                        if (cursor != null) {
                            if (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                                val dataColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA)
                                val filePath = cursor.getString(dataColumn)
                                val name = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME)
                                return@map Picture()
                                        .apply {
                                            this.name = cursor.getString(name)
                                            this.path = filePath
                                        }
                            }
                            cursor.close()
                        }
                        return@map Picture()
                    }
                    return@map Picture()
                }
```

These pictures are then added to an Object, called file.

```
fun listenForGeneralPictures(observe: Flowable<Picture>?) {
        observe?.apply {
            generalPictureDisposable = concatMap {
                if (it.name?.isNotEmpty() == true
                        && it.path?.isNotEmpty() == true
                        && file != null) {
                    it.categoryNr = Picture.CAT_GENERAL_PICTURES
                    file?.generalPictures?.add(it)
                    Log.d(it.name.toString(), "pictureAfter")
                    return@concatMap fileRepository.update(file!!)
                } else {
                    return@concatMap Flowable.just(file)
                }

            }.subscribe({
                cachedFile?.generalPictures = it!!.generalPictures
            }, errorUtils::onError)
        }

    }
```

I'm using this, to get to the path and set the image to an Imageview:

```
  override fun showPicture(path: String?) {
    val pictureFile = File(path)
    ivDraw?.setImageUri(FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, this.applicationContext.packageName + ".provider", pictureFile))
}
```

But when I do I get an error:

> System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   /external_path/DCIM/Camera/20180801_115654(1).jpg (No such file or
>   directory)
>               at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
>               at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:146)
>               at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:99)
>               at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:708)
>               at com.insypro.inspector3.ui.custom.picturedraw.DrawImageView.rotateImageToTakenDirection(DrawImageView.kt:108)
>               at com.insypro.inspector3.ui.custom.picturedraw.DrawImageView.setImageUri(DrawImageView.kt:54)
>               at com.insypro.inspector3.ui.picture.PictureViewActivity.showPicture(PictureViewActivity.kt:124)
>               at com.insypro.inspector3.ui.picture.PicturePresenter.processPicture(PicturePresenter.kt:69)
>               at com.insypro.inspector3.ui.picture.PicturePresenter.access$processPicture(PicturePresenter.kt:24)
>               at com.insypro.inspector3.ui.picture.PicturePresenter$loadDataPicture$1.accept(PicturePresenter.kt:51)

I also have a fileprovider file and everything needed in the manifest:

```
   <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"
            tools:replace="android:resource"/>
    </provider>
```

and the paths:

```
<paths>
<files-path name="files" path="." />
<cache-path name="cache" path="/"/>
<external-path name="external_path" path="." />
<external-files-path name="external_files" path="." />
```

Comment: `MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA` will just open the camera it will not save image or create a file . You need to use `MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` with `EXTRA_OUTPUT` extras .

Comment: That is not needed. I have to add, that before the fileprovider it was working perfectly. It's only since then, that I'm getting this error.

Comment: I don't get it . Where did you get the path to pass to `showPicture()` method then ? I am kind of  Dumb .

Comment: give package name of your project android:authorities="com.exa.project.fileprovider"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first of all you need to understand where a **FileProvider**
 is for. It is for sharing local files to *other* apps in a safe way: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider

You are only using the image file only in your *own* application. Therefore there is no need to use the `FileProvider` at all.

To show the image, use a `BitmapFactory`, note that `your_path` is the full path to the image, not changed by a `FileProvider`:

```
val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(your_path);
ivDraw.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I was already wondering if using a fileprovider was a good idea. A bitmapfactory is a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

> I take images, using the following intent:

That `Intent` action simply opens a camera app, one of hundreds of possible apps. Whether the user takes pictures with that camera app is up to the user.

> To make this work, I also have an Observer

There is no requirement for a camera app to have its images available via any `ContentProvider`, such as `MediaStore`.

There is no requirement for `dataColumn` to return a filesystem path.

There is no requirement for `dataColumn` to return a filesystem path that you have read access to.

IOW, this code will not be reliable across the ~24,000 Android device models and ~2 billion Android users.

> I'm using this, to get to the path and set the image to an Imageview

Do not use `setImageUri()`. [The documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageURI(android.net.Uri)) specifically advises against it.

Do not use `FileProvider` here. That is for sharing content with other apps, not for internal use within your own app. Moreover, because you have no idea where `dataColumn` will point, you cannot configure `FileProvider` to serve arbitrary files.

Instead, pass your "path" to your favorite image-loading library (e.g., Glide, Picasso), which can attempt to load your photo on a background thread and then populate your `ImageView` with the result.

Comment: Thank you for your time to answer CommonsWare. You are correct, I still need to learn a lot. Also, my English isn't that good,so I apologise for that.

I'm going to follow Giovanni's advice, because you're right, I don't need a fileprovider for this. 
The code that was given to me, confused me so much, that I made it worse.
I've been using the observer because I want to make multiple pictures in a row, and I have no idea how else to do this.

Comment: @KlaartjeDeBacker: "I want to make multiple pictures in a row, and I have no idea how else to do this" -- you cannot really do that via `Intent` actions. Use the camera APIs directly, or via a third-party library (e.g., Fotoapparat, CameraKit-Android). You can take as many pictures as you want, and you control where the photos get saved.